# JSTree and IE(7/8): all non-leaf nodes open after tree loading

Tags: jquery, json, internet-explorer, jquery-plugins, jstree

i have some issues with JSTree IE(7 and 8): after tree loading, all the non-leaf nodes are open (the tree is loaded from a json data structure, with only one non-leaf node with the "state" object setted to "open" and all the other to "closed"). the same code work properly on ff, opera and safari.

here is the js code: http://jsfiddle.net/yuXxx/

and here is the json generated code (validated): http://pastebin.com/Zw1KYEK5

anybody could help me?
tnx

Answer (score 0):

The above issue happening in chrome also.